# Giving inline-block divs margin

Tags: css, html

I was provided advice on how to center align my divs which was great but now im having an issue where the divs do stack on screen sizes as they should but I need to give them margin but no matter how much margin I give them changes anything?

HTML:

```
  <div class="categorylist">
      <div class="categorypost">1</div>
      <div class="categorypost">2</div>
      <div class="categorypost">3</div>
      <div class="categorypost">4</div>
      <div class="categorypost">5</div>
      <div class="categorypost">6</div>
   </div>
```

CSS :

```
.categorylist{
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;   
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.categorypost{
    height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: What kind of margin are you adding? You don't need `margin:0 auto;` on the `.categorypost class.

Comment: your margin:0 auto; is overwritting your margin-bottom. is this intended?

Comment: give margin 0 auto to the parent and for inner div use float:left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then here as an example

html

```
<div class="categorylist">


        <div class="categorypost">1</div>

        <div class="categorypost">2</div>

        <div class="categorypost">3</div>

        <div class="categorypost">4</div>

        <div class="categorypost">5</div>

        <div class="categorypost">6</div>


    </div>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.categorylist{
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;   
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}


.categorypost {
    height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9faLL/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Remove your last line:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

You are overriding your `margin-bottom` with it :

```
.categorypost{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin:0 auto;        /* Culprit */
}
```

Comment: ...and in any case the `margin: 0 auto` isn't doing anything. The elements are centered via `text-align` on the parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D Indeed. Editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

Set `overflow: hidden` on the `.categorypost` so as to force the browser to compute the elements again and detect the margin.

http://codepen.io/AndreiPham/pen/vhkas/

Comment: The elements **aren't floated**

Comment: Yep, they aren't. My bad. Frankly, it appears that `overflow: hidden` still managed to solve the problem because it affects the height of the divs. Anyway, @user3435159, you should actually follow Andrew Pope's answer, as this is sort of an aid not a 'problem remover'.

Answer (score 2):

On .categorypost you are setting the margin-bottom twice with `margin: 0 auto;` and overriding the first:

```
.categorypost {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Change to this:

```
.categorypost {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Shorthand:

```
.categorypost {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understood everything of your question, but I guess you want your div not to be collapsed.

First, you don't need `margin: 0 auto` on your `.categorypost` block, because your layout is centered with `margin: 0 auto;` on your `.categorylist` block.

See this site to know how margin property works: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Now, if you want to add spaces vertically between your `.categorypost` blocks, you can do it with `margin` like you did, but your second `margin: 0 auto` overrided your `margin-bottom: 20px`.

For example, `margin-bottom: 20px;` or `margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;` if you want to add margins on top and bottom to get it prettier.

See this live here: http://jsfiddle.net/9etcQ/